# Drawing multiple route Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to draw multiple routes based on the directions service in Google, the code goes below

p/s:Data is a list I obtained from my json call

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
route = data[i];

start = new google.maps.LatLng(route.from_lat,route.from_lng);
end = new google.maps.LatLng(route.to_lat,route.to_lng);

var request = {
origin:start,
destination:end,
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

var rendererOptions = {
preserveViewport: true,         
suppressMarkers:true,
routeIndex:i
};


directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);                
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    console.log(result);

if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
}});
```

I can't seems to find much relevant information from forums, is my best bet to obtain all the individual traffic information and draw again using polyline? And also, how do I make sure the loop carries on only when my directionDisplay.setDirections is done?

Regards,
Andy

Comment: what if routes are intersecting then google maps shows latest route only . How to deal with htis situation?

Answer (score 15):

You need separate google.maps.DirectionsRenderer object for each route. Something like that:

```
var routes = [{origin: ..., destination: ...}, {origin: ..., destination: ...}, {origin: ..., destination: ...}];
var rendererOptions = {
    preserveViewport: true,         
    suppressMarkers:true,
    routeIndex:i
};
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

routes.each(function(route){
    var request = {
        origin: route.origin,
        destination: route.destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        console.log(result);

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using prototype.js, so your method of array walking may differ.

Comment: You can also store the polygons in an array and draw it manually if you want to avoid to create to many directions objects.

Comment: if routes intersects then it draws latest route =. How to deal with this situation?\

Answer (score 4):

I have get the solution for multiple routes based on the directions service in Google
For more reference [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/fjUqK/)!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my={directionsSVC:new google.maps.DirectionsService(),maps:{},routes:{}};
    /**
        * base-class     
        * @param points optional array array of lat+lng-values defining a route
        * @return object Route
    **/                     
    function Route(points) {
        this.origin       = null;
        this.destination  = null;
        this.waypoints    = [];
        if(points && points.length>1) { this.setPoints(points);}
        return this; 
    };

    /**
        *  draws route on a map 
        *              
        * @param map object google.maps.Map 
        * @return object Route
    **/                    
    Route.prototype.drawRoute = function(map) {
        var _this=this;
        my.directionsSVC.route(
          {"origin": this.origin,
           "destination": this.destination,
           "waypoints": this.waypoints,
           "travelMode": google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
          },
          function(res,sts) {
                if(sts==google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                    if(!_this.directionsRenderer) { _this.directionsRenderer=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ "draggable":true }); }
                    _this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
                    _this.directionsRenderer.setDirections(res);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(_this.directionsRenderer,"directions_changed", function() { _this.setPoints(); } );
                }   
          });
        return _this;
    };

    /**
    * sets map for directionsRenderer     
    * @param map object google.maps.Map
    **/             
    Route.prototype.setGMap = function(map){ this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map); };

    /**
    * sets origin, destination and waypoints for a route 
    * from a directionsResult or the points-param when passed    
    * 
    * @param points optional array array of lat+lng-values defining a route
    * @return object Route        
    **/
    Route.prototype.setPoints = function(points) {
        this.origin = null;
        this.destination = null;
        this.waypoints = [];
        if(points) {
          for(var p=0;p<points.length;++p){
            this.waypoints.push({location:new google.maps.LatLng(points[p][0], points[p][1]),stopover:false});
          }
          this.origin=this.waypoints.shift().location;
          this.destination=this.waypoints.pop().location;
        }
        else {
          var route=this.directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0];
          for(var l=0;l<route.legs.length;++l) {
            if(!this.origin)this.origin=route.legs[l].start_location;
            this.destination = route.legs[l].end_location;

            for(var w=0;w<route.legs[l].via_waypoints.length;++w) { this.waypoints.push({location:route.legs[l].via_waypoints[w], stopover:false});}
          }
          //the route has been modified by the user when you are here you may call now this.getPoints() and work with the result
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
    * retrieves points for a route 
    *         
    * @return array         
    **/
    Route.prototype.getPoints = function() {
      var points=[[this.origin.lat(),this.origin.lng()]];

      for(var w=0;w<this.waypoints.length;++w) { points.push([this.waypoints[w].location.lat(), this.waypoints[w].location.lng()]);}
      points.push([this.destination.lat(), this.destination.lng()]);
      return points;
    };

    function initialize() {
      var myOptions = { zoom: 8, center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        my.maps.map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        my.routes.r0 = new Route([[55.930385, -3.118425],[50.909700, -1.40435]]).drawRoute(my.maps.map1);
        my.routes.r1 = new Route([[51.454513, -2.58790],[52.6308859, 1.2973550]]).drawRoute(my.maps.map1);

        my.routes.rx=new Route();
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="height:300px;width:300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have everything else set up, but are only getting one route to show up on your map, the problem is likely that you are not resetting the `DirectionsRenderer` to `null` before reusing it.

Each `DirectionsRenderer` can only be used to render one route. So if you are cycling through an array and creating a variable like `renderer` each time, you have to make sure to reset it to `null` and create a new one.

For example

```
for (all routes){
     directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(optionsDictionary);
     //call route(), define call back function, etc.
     directionsRenderer = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In image u can see 2 routes in single map

Drawing multiple route Google Map with waypoints on route

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

  var map;

  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;

  var position;
  var marker = [];
  var polyline = [];
  var poly2 = [];
  var poly = null;
  var startLocation = [];
  var endLocation = [];
  var timerHandle = [];




  var stops_data = [[ {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.05242,"Longitude":72.53375}},

                      {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.03007,"Longitude":72.59664}}

                    ] ,[ {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.00959,"Longitude":72.56189}},
                         {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.05754,"Longitude":72.55302}}
                       ]];



  var a,z,b;

  var add;
  var map; 

  var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;

  var myPano;   
  var panoClient;
  var nextPanoId;


  //    var locations=new Array(new google.maps.LatLng(34.04429454929703, -118.22793351693724),new google.maps.LatLng(33.688522885631706, -116.15151750131224));


    //  var locations2=new Array(
    //      new google.maps.LatLng(32.69561555501597, -117.06338273568724),new google.maps.LatLng(34.525395303965354, -117.27212297006224));





      var directionsDisplay = [];

      directionsDisplay[0] = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          suppressMarkers: false,
          suppressInfoWindows: true
        });


      directionsDisplay[1] = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          suppressMarkers: false,
          suppressInfoWindows: true
        });

      var map;
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.5584308, -70.8597732), zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

      function initialize() 
      {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


     //   Setroute(locations[0],locations[1],directionsDisplay[0]);

       // Setroute(locations2[0],locations2[1],directionsDisplay[1]);


        Tour_startUp(stops_data[0]);

        window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay[0]);
       // window.tour.fitBounds(map);



        if (stops_data[0].length > 1)
            window.tour.calcRoute(stops_data[0],directionsService, directionsDisplay[0]);



        Tour_startUp(stops_data[1]);
        window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay[1]);
        window.tour.calcRoute(stops_data[1],directionsService, directionsDisplay[1]);
       // window.tour.fitBounds(map);





      }





function Tour_startUp(stops) {

    //  alert('first'+stops.length);     

    if (!window.tour) window.tour = {
        updateStops: function (newStops) {
            stops = newStops;
        },


        // map: google map object
        // directionsDisplay: google directionsDisplay object (comes in empty)
        loadMap: function (map, dirdis) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(51.507937, -0.076188), // default to London
                mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map.setOptions(myOptions);
            dirdis.setMap(map);
        },



        calcRoute: function (stops_new,directionsService, dirdis) {
            var batches = [];
            var itemsPerBatch = 10; // google API max = 10 - 1 start, 1 stop, and 8 waypoints
            var itemsCounter = 0;
            var wayptsExist = stops_new.length > 0;
            var time= [];
            while (wayptsExist) {
                var subBatch = [];
                var subitemsCounter = 0;

               // alert('second'+stops_new.length);        
        //alert(stops_new[0].Geometry.Latitude +' ===== ' +stops_new[0].Geometry.Longitude);


                for (var j = itemsCounter; j < stops_new.length; j++) {
                    subitemsCounter++;

                //alert(stops[j].Geometry.Time);



                    subBatch.push({
                        location: new window.google.maps.LatLng(stops_new[j].Geometry.Latitude, stops_new[j].Geometry.Longitude),
                        stopover: true

                    });

                   //time.push(stops[j].Geometry.Time);

                    if (subitemsCounter == itemsPerBatch)
                        break;
                }

                itemsCounter += subitemsCounter;
                batches.push(subBatch);
                wayptsExist = itemsCounter < stops_new.length;
                // If it runs again there are still points. Minus 1 before continuing to
                // start up with end of previous tour leg
                itemsCounter--;
            }

            // now we should have a 2 dimensional array with a list of a list of waypoints
            var combinedResults;
            var unsortedResults = [{}]; // to hold the counter and the results themselves as they come back, to later sort
            var directionsResultsReturned = 0;




            for (var k = 0; k < batches.length; k++) {
                var lastIndex = batches[k].length - 1;
                var start = batches[k][0].location;
                var end = batches[k][lastIndex].location;

                // trim first and last entry from array
                var waypts = [];
                waypts = batches[k];
                waypts.splice(0, 1);
                waypts.splice(waypts.length - 1, 1);

                var request = 
                    {
                    origin: start,
                    destination: end,
                    waypoints: waypts,
                    travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
                };

              //  alert('start'+start);

             //   alert('end'+end);

                (function (kk) {
                    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {



                        if (status == window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                             polyline[0] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                 path: [],
                                 strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
                                 strokeWeight: 3
                                 });


                             poly2[0] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                 path: [],
                                 strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
                                 strokeWeight: 3
                                 });     


                            var unsortedResult = { order: kk, result: result };
                            unsortedResults.push(unsortedResult);

                            directionsResultsReturned++;

                            if (directionsResultsReturned == batches.length) // we've received all the results. put to map
                            {
                                // sort the returned values into their correct order
                                unsortedResults.sort(function (a, b) { return parseFloat(a.order) - parseFloat(b.order); });
                                var count = 0;
                                for (var key in unsortedResults) {
                                    if (unsortedResults[key].result != null) {
                                        if (unsortedResults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                            if (count == 0) // first results. new up the combinedResults object
                                                combinedResults = unsortedResults[key].result;
                                            else {
                                                // only building up legs, overview_path, and bounds in my consolidated object. This is not a complete
                                                // directionResults object, but enough to draw a path on the map, which is all I need
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].legs);
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].overview_path);

                                                combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getNorthEast());
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getSouthWest());
                                            }
                                            count++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                dirdis.setDirections(combinedResults);


                                var legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs;

                                var path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path;

                                //alert(path.length);

                             //  alert(legs.length);

                              //setRoutes(legs[0].start_location,legs[legs.length-1].end_location);



                                for (var i=0; i < legs.length;i++)
                                    {
                                          var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                                          markerletter += i;
                                  markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);

                                  if (i == 0) { 

                                    //marker[0] = createMarker2(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
                                  }

                                  var steps = legs[i].steps;

                                //  alert('arrival time : '+legs[i].arrival_time.text);

                            //  var duration = steps.duration_in_traffic;

                              // alert(duration.text);

                                  for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) 
                                  {

                                      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;

                                      for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) 
                                          {
                                          polyline[0].getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                                          //bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                                             }
                                  }



                                //  createMarker(directionsDisplay.getMap(),legs[i].start_location,"marker"+i,"some text for marker "+i+"<br>"+legs[i].start_address,markerletter);   
                                }
                                    // Marker for start point 
                                createMarker(dirdis.getMap(),legs[0].start_location,"marker"+0,"Start Point<br>"+legs[0].start_address,'A');


                                var i=legs.length;
                                var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                                  markerletter += i;
                                markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);

                                // marker for End Point 
                                createMarker(dirdis.getMap(),legs[legs.length-1].end_location,"marker"+i,"End Point <br>"+legs[legs.length-1].end_address,'B');

                                polyline[0].setMap(map);

                                //startAnimation(0);  
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })(k);
            }
        }
    };
}


var icons = new Array();
icons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mapIcons/marker_red.png",
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));



function getMarkerImage(iconStr) {

//alert(iconStr);

   if ((typeof(iconStr)=="undefined") || (iconStr==null)) { 
      iconStr = "red"; 
   }

if(iconStr == 'A')
{
   // for start point 


   if (!icons[iconStr]) {
      icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-start.png",
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
   } 

}
if (iconStr == 'B')
{

    // for end point


    if (!icons[iconStr]) {
          icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-end.png",
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
          new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
          // The origin for this image is 0,0.
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
          new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
       } 


    }
return icons[iconStr];
}
  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.

  var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapIcons/marker_red.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));



  var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
      // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
      // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
      new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
      // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
      // coordinate.
  var iconShape = {
      coord: [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],
      type: 'poly'
  };


function createMarker(map, latlng, label, html, color) {

//alert(color);
//  alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");


    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        shadow: iconShadow,
        icon: getMarkerImage(color),
        shape: iconShape,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        marker.myname = label;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });


    return marker;
}

function createMarkerForStops(map, latlng, label, html, color) {
    // alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");


   var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: label,
            //icon:'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/stop.png',
            icon:'icon/stop.png',
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
            });
            marker.myname = label;


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        return marker;
    }


      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```