# Display multiple routes on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show multiple routes on google map but It is showing only one. Can you please what I am doing wrong?

`<div class="searchmap" style="float:left;margin-left:1%"  id="map"></div>`

```
var map          = null;
var markerPoints = [];

var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
function initialize() 
{   
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {scrollwheel:false, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, mapTypeControl: false, streetViewControl: false, center:new google.maps.LatLng(19.0759837, 72.87765590000004), zoom:13});


  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}


function calcRoute(flat, flng, tlat, tlng)
{
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(flat, flng);
    var end   = new google.maps.LatLng(tlat, tlng);     

    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: false,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        console.log(result);

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
} 

calcRoute("19.210430", "72.843422", "19.109858", "72.878433");
calcRoute("19.228977", "72.856812", "19.117302", "72.884041");
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing multiple route Google Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040965/drawing-multiple-route-google-map)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Display multiple routes on google map with waypoints and direction arrow
==============
```

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB4Tw.png)!

```
![In image u can see 2 routes with direction arrow][1]

 <style>
    html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
    </style>


     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script>




      var directionsService;
      var stepDisplay;

      var position;
      var marker = [];
      var polyline = [];
      var poly2 = [];
      var poly = null;
      var startLocation = [];
      var endLocation = [];
      var timerHandle = [];




      var stops_data = [[ {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.05242,"Longitude":72.53375}},

                          {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.03007,"Longitude":72.59664}}

                        ] ,[ {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.00959,"Longitude":72.56189}},
                             {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.05754,"Longitude":72.55302}}
                           ]];



      var a,z,b;

      var add;


      var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
      var infowindow = null;


       infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


      var myPano;   
      var panoClient;
      var nextPanoId;








          var directionsDisplay = [];

          directionsDisplay[0] = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
              suppressMarkers: true

            });


          directionsDisplay[1] = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
              suppressMarkers: true

            });

          var map;
          var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.5584308, -70.8597732), zoom: 3,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

          function initialize() 
          {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


         //   Setroute(locations[0],locations[1],directionsDisplay[0]);

           // Setroute(locations2[0],locations2[1],directionsDisplay[1]);


            Tour_startUp(stops_data[0]);

            window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay[0]);
           window.tour.fitBounds(stops_data[0],map);



            if (stops_data[0].length > 1)
                window.tour.calcRoute(stops_data[0],directionsService, directionsDisplay[0]);



            Tour_startUp(stops_data[1]);
            window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay[1]);
            window.tour.calcRoute(stops_data[1],directionsService, directionsDisplay[1]);
            window.tour.fitBounds(stops_data[1],map);





          }




    function fx(o)
    {
      if(o && o.legs)
      {
        for(l=0;l<o.legs.length;l++)
        {
          var leg=o.legs[l];
          for(var s=0;s<leg.steps.length;++s)
          {
            var step=leg.steps[s],
                a=(step.lat_lngs.length)?step.lat_lngs[0]:step.start_point,
                z=(step.lat_lngs.length)?step.lat_lngs[1]:step.end_point,
                dir=((Math.atan2(z.lng()-a.lng(),z.lat()-a.lat())*180)/Math.PI)+360,
                ico=((dir-(dir%3))%120);
                new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: a,
                  icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_'+ico+'.png',
                                              new google.maps.Size(24,24),
                                              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                                              new google.maps.Point(12,12)
                                             ),
            map: map,
            title: Math.round((dir>360)?dir-360:dir)+'°'
          });

          }
        }
      }
    }


    function Tour_startUp(stops) {

        //  alert('first'+stops.length);     

        if (!window.tour) window.tour = {
            updateStops: function (newStops) {
                stops = newStops;
            },


            // map: google map object
            // directionsDisplay: google directionsDisplay object (comes in empty)
            loadMap: function (map, dirdis) {
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(51.507937, -0.076188), // default to London
                    mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map.setOptions(myOptions);
                dirdis.setMap(map);
            },
         fitBounds: function (stops_data,map) {
                var bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                // extend bounds for each record 
                for( var x in stops_data) {
                    var myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(stops_data[x].Geometry.Latitude, stops_data[x].Geometry.Longitude);
                    bounds.extend(myLatlng);
                }
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            },
            calcRoute: function (stops_new,directionsService, dirdis) {
                var batches = [];
                var itemsPerBatch = 10; // google API max = 10 - 1 start, 1 stop, and 8 waypoints
                var itemsCounter = 0;
                var wayptsExist = stops_new.length > 0;
                var time= [];
                while (wayptsExist) {
                    var subBatch = [];
                    var subitemsCounter = 0;

                   // alert('second'+stops_new.length);        
            //alert(stops_new[0].Geometry.Latitude +' ===== ' +stops_new[0].Geometry.Longitude);


                    for (var j = itemsCounter; j < stops_new.length; j++) {
                        subitemsCounter++;

                    //alert(stops[j].Geometry.Time);



                        subBatch.push({
                            location: new window.google.maps.LatLng(stops_new[j].Geometry.Latitude, stops_new[j].Geometry.Longitude),
                            stopover: true

                        });

                       //time.push(stops[j].Geometry.Time);

                        if (subitemsCounter == itemsPerBatch)
                            break;
                    }

                    itemsCounter += subitemsCounter;
                    batches.push(subBatch);
                    wayptsExist = itemsCounter < stops_new.length;
                    // If it runs again there are still points. Minus 1 before continuing to
                    // start up with end of previous tour leg
                    itemsCounter--;
                }

                // now we should have a 2 dimensional array with a list of a list of waypoints
                var combinedResults;
                var unsortedResults = [{}]; // to hold the counter and the results themselves as they come back, to later sort
                var directionsResultsReturned = 0;




                for (var k = 0; k < batches.length; k++) {
                    var lastIndex = batches[k].length - 1;
                    var start = batches[k][0].location;
                    var end = batches[k][lastIndex].location;

                    // trim first and last entry from array
                    var waypts = [];
                    waypts = batches[k];
                    waypts.splice(0, 1);
                    waypts.splice(waypts.length - 1, 1);

                    var request = 
                        {
                        origin: start,
                        destination: end,
                        waypoints: waypts,
                        travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
                    };

                  //  alert('start'+start);

                 //   alert('end'+end);


                    (function (kk) {
                        directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {



                            if (status == window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {


                                 fx(result.routes[0]);

                                 polyline[0] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                     path: [],
                                     strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
                                     strokeWeight: 3
                                     });


                                 poly2[0] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                     path: [],
                                     strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
                                     strokeWeight: 3
                                     });     


                                var unsortedResult = { order: kk, result: result };
                                unsortedResults.push(unsortedResult);

                                directionsResultsReturned++;

                                if (directionsResultsReturned == batches.length) // we've received all the results. put to map
                                {
                                    // sort the returned values into their correct order
                                    unsortedResults.sort(function (a, b) { return parseFloat(a.order) - parseFloat(b.order); });
                                    var count = 0;
                                    for (var key in unsortedResults) {
                                        if (unsortedResults[key].result != null) {
                                            if (unsortedResults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                                if (count == 0) // first results. new up the combinedResults object
                                                    combinedResults = unsortedResults[key].result;
                                                else {
                                                    // only building up legs, overview_path, and bounds in my consolidated object. This is not a complete
                                                    // directionResults object, but enough to draw a path on the map, which is all I need
                                                    combinedResults.routes[0].legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].legs);
                                                    combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].overview_path);

                                                    combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getNorthEast());
                                                    combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getSouthWest());
                                                }
                                                count++;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    dirdis.setDirections(combinedResults);


                                    var legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs;

                                    var path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path;

                                    //alert(path.length);

                                 //  alert(legs.length);

                                  //setRoutes(legs[0].start_location,legs[legs.length-1].end_location);



                                    for (var i=0; i < legs.length;i++)
                                        {
                                              var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                                              markerletter += i;
                                      markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);

                                      if (i == 0) { 

                                        //marker[0] = createMarker2(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
                                      }

                                      var steps = legs[i].steps;

                                    //  alert('arrival time : '+legs[i].arrival_time.text);

                                //  var duration = steps.duration_in_traffic;

                                  // alert(duration.text);

                                      for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) 
                                      {

                                          var nextSegment = steps[j].path;

                                          for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) 
                                              {
                                              polyline[0].getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                                              //bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                                                 }
                                      }



                                    //  createMarker(directionsDisplay.getMap(),legs[i].start_location,"marker"+i,"some text for marker "+i+"<br>"+legs[i].start_address,markerletter);   
                                    }
                                        // Marker for start point 
                                    createMarker(dirdis.getMap(),legs[0].start_location,"marker"+0,"Start Point<br>"+legs[0].start_address,'A');


                                    var i=legs.length;
                                    var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                                      markerletter += i;
                                    markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);

                                    // marker for End Point 
                                    createMarker(dirdis.getMap(),legs[legs.length-1].end_location,"marker"+i,"End Point <br>"+legs[legs.length-1].end_address,'B');

                                    polyline[0].setMap(map);

                                    //startAnimation(0);  
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    })(k);
                }
            }
        };
    }


    var icons = new Array();
    icons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mapIcons/marker_red.png",
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
          new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
          // The origin for this image is 0,0.
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
          new google.maps.Point(9, 34));



    function getMarkerImage(iconStr) {

    //alert(iconStr);

       if ((typeof(iconStr)=="undefined") || (iconStr==null)) { 
          iconStr = "red"; 
       }

    if(iconStr == 'A')
    {
       // for start point 


       if (!icons[iconStr]) {
          icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-start.png",
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
          new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
          // The origin for this image is 0,0.
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
          new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
       } 

    }
    if (iconStr == 'B')
    {

        // for end point


        if (!icons[iconStr]) {
              icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-end.png",
              // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
              new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
              // The origin for this image is 0,0.
              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
              new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
           } 


        }
    return icons[iconStr];
    }
      // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
      // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
      // in the top left of the image.

      // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
      // increase in the X direction to the right and in
      // the Y direction down.

      var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapIcons/marker_red.png',
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
          new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
          // The origin for this image is 0,0.
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
          new google.maps.Point(9, 34));



      var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
          // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
          // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
          new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
          // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
          // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
          // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
          // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
          // coordinate.
      var iconShape = {
          coord: [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],
          type: 'poly'
      };


    function createMarker(map, latlng, label, html, color) {

    //alert(color);
    //  alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");


        var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;


    //    alert('creatMarker'+contentString);


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            shadow: iconShadow,
            icon: getMarkerImage(color),
            shape: iconShape,
            title: label,
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
            });
            marker.myname = label;

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });


        return marker;
    }




          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

    <div id="map_canvas"></div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB4Tw.png
```

Comment: Here is code for multiple routes on same google map..
 If you want to display more than one route, you need multiple google.maps.DirectionsRenderer().
I have created array of **directionsDisaply[]** objects

Answer (score 5):

Here you go.. [the full explaination](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/GIS_and_GPS/Q_26617895.html) , credit goes to [the author](http://www.experts-exchange.com/members/jagku.html)

```
    function drawMap() {

        var directionDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(51.47482547819850,-0.37739553384529);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: start
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    function renderDirections(result) { 
        var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map); 
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(result); 
      }     

    function requestDirections(start, end) { 
      directionsService.route({ 
        origin: start, 
        destination: end, 
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING 
      }, function(result) { 
        renderDirections(result); 
      }); 
    } 

    requestDirections('(51.47482547819850,-0.37739553384529)', '(51.59512428598160,-0.17190814889409)'); 
    requestDirections('EC1V 0AH', '(51.47615506206120, -0.37795315370703)');  

  }
```

you need to create an instance of `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();` EVERYTIME you draw the route to make it visible ;)

Comment: Please consider quoting the important parts of the explanation in the answer for context.

Comment: Im sorry @NickUdell, I thought the link would explain my answer. But I just realized that it was broken. ;)
Thank You for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Your `directionsDisplay` variable is an instance of `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()` and that can only hold one set of directions at a time. If you want to display more than one route, you need multiple `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I am not getting you.. How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get multiple routes we can add `provideRouteAlternatives = true` inside request object while calling `route()` of `DirectionsService` object. See [Directions Requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests).

This method will return array of routes if available with their name in `summary` key.

Now we can display these routes on view and on click of each route we can pass route object and can render the direction by `setDirections()` of `DirectionsRenderer` object. See [Displaying the DirectionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DisplayingResults)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Waypoints in Directions</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your-key&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
  defer
  ></script>
  <style type="text/css">

    html,
    body {
      height: 99%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map {
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      width: 99%;
      height: 100%;
    }

  </style>
  <script>
    "use strict";

    function initMap() {

      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: {
         lat: 19.8762,
         lng: 75.3433
       }
     }); 

      const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 

     let points =    [
     {
       origin: {
         lat: 19.9974533,
         lng: 73.78980229999999
       },
       destination:  {
        lat: 19.0759837,
        lng: 72.8776559
      },

      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, 
    {
      origin: {
        lat: 21.1458,
        lng: 79.0882
      },
      destination:  {
       lat: 18.5204,
       lng: 73.8567
     },
         // waypoints: waypts,
         optimizeWaypoints: true,
         travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
       }
       ]

       for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
         calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,points[i])   

       } 
       

       function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,points) {
        let directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        // const waypts = [{
        //   location: {
        //     lat: 19.8762,
        //     lng: 75.3433
        //   },
        // }, 
        // ]; 



        directionsService.route(
         points,
         (response, status) => {
          console.log(response);
          if (status === "OK") {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
            directionsRenderer.setMap(map);  

          } else {
            window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
          }
        }
        );
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

</body>
</html>
```