# Interactive Android Google Map that returns a single route

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I implement an interactive map using Google Maps API that prompts a user to select a route? For example, the Place Picker (https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) is an interactive map that allows the user to search and select a location and I can get that information using `onActivityResult()`. I am looking to do something similar, but for a specific route from point A to B.

The easiest way I can think of for getting this information currently is to use the PlacePicker to get the user to choose origin and destination. Then I would use the Directions API to get the available routes. Then plot the available routes on a map and prompt the user to choose one. But this way seems a bit messy and I would like it if the user could just do everything in 1 interactive map that returns a specific route to the app.

Any suggestions on implementing the cleaner solution? What combination of Google Maps APIs could I use to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [javascript-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909399/display-multiple-routes-on-google-map) acheives something similar to what you are asking, but not with the Android API.  Two possible ways forward would be:

- Use the API in a similar way to them, with waypoints and directional 
  arrows.
- Do what they did in a browser (for example in HTMLView) and put an
  invisible View on top to get the clicks and select the route that way
  (change the color of the selected route after getting the click).

The key information from the answer linked and others around the web seems to be to use Multiple DirectionsRenderer objects, possibly stacked in an Array.